# Setting 100% height of an inline-block when parent has no height set

Tags: html, css

I have a "simple" css problem, I want two columns to be of the same height, using 
{ display:**inline-block** } 
and it fails miserably when the parent container has no height set (the goal would be to not have the parent to have any height set, because **it should be defined by the highest column**.
I would like it to be Javascript free if possible.

```
<div class="line-wrapper">
    <div class="column1">How to make that of 100% of its parent line-wrapper?</div>
    <div class="column2" style="height:200px">Random content with a larger height</div>
</div>
```

**Full JSFiddle is available here:**

http://jsfiddle.net/darknessm0404/1a4yyyc9/1/

Is there any solution for that kind of problem?

***Note: It must work with vertical-align as well***

Comment: My answer works with `vertical-align`. http://jsfiddle.net/1a4yyyc9/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can change these to use `display:table-row` and `display:table-cell` for a CSS only solution:

```
.line-wrapper {
font-size:0;  /* CANNOT CHANGE : For no space between inline-blocks */
position:relative; /* Tried to get the 100% working, but it fails*/
display:table-row;
}

.line-wrapper > div {
font-size:14px; /* CANNOT CHANGE : For no space between inline-blocks */
display:table-cell; /* CANNOT CHANGE : NO float allowed */
vertical-align:top;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1a4yyyc9/3/

Comment: yeah i would go with this solution much cleaner. Out of curiosity are there any side effects to using display:table-row and display:table-cell when not using them in a table?

Comment: No @Quince , I'd say not. Its long supported CSS and in fact table cells are not exactly block level elements, so if you ever wanted to animate their height/width, using div with table CSS would allow for a smooth animation and not the jumpy show/hide that you would get with a table cell.

Answer (score 2):

The CSS only solution that I have seen work for this type of problem is to apply a massive padding and then a massive negative margin to the divs which has the effect sucking the divs down, then it is a case of hiding the extra space created in the container div.

apply margin and padding

```
.line-wrapper > div {
    font-size:14px; /* CANNOT CHANGE : For no space between inline-blocks */
    display:inline-block; /* CANNOT CHANGE : NO float allowed */
    vertical-align:top;
    margin-bottom:-9999px;
    padding-bottom:9999px;
}
```

and then to hide all the space

```
.line-wrapper {
    font-size:0;  /* CANNOT CHANGE : For no space between inline-blocks */
    position:relative; /* Tried to get the 100% working, but it fails*/
    overflow:hidden
}
```

example

```css
.line-wrapper {
    font-size:0;  /* CANNOT CHANGE : For no space between inline-blocks */
    position:relative; /* Tried to get the 100% working, but it fails*/
    overflow:hidden
}



.line-wrapper > div {
    font-size:14px; /* CANNOT CHANGE : For no space between inline-blocks */
    display:inline-block; /* CANNOT CHANGE : NO float allowed */
    vertical-align:top;
    margin-bottom:-9999px;
    padding-bottom:9999px;
}

.column1 {
    width:30%; /* CANNOT CHANGE */
    height:100%; /* <-- Expected to work (should be of the size of .line-wrapper), but it does not */
}
.column2 {
    width:60%;  /* CANNOT CHANGE */
}

/* Unuseful code, just to show a few colors */
.column1 {
    background-color:rgba(0,255,255,0.2);
}
.column2 {
    background-color:rgba(150,200,60,0.2);}
}
```

```html
<div class="line-wrapper">
    <div class="column1">How to make that of 100% of its parent line-wrapper?</div>
    <div class="column2">Random contentRandom contentRandom contentRandom contentRandom contentRandom contentRandom contentRandom contentRandom contentRandom contentRandom contentRandom contentRandom contentRandom contentRandom contentRandom contentRandom contentRandom contentRandom contentRandom contentRandom contentRandom contentRandom contentRandom contentRandom contentRandom contentRandom contentRandom contentRandom</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems to work, it seems more like a hack than a something standard, but it seems to fail on the { vertical-align: middle; } and it seems to fail in Chrome.

Comment: it is certainly a hack and although i have not tried it with the `vertical-align:middle` the version i posted is working for me on chrome 38

Comment: I've checked and it works too on IE9+ except for the vertical align property.

Comment: do you mean it must work with `vertical-aligh:middle`